# How to start mongodb with new dbPath in a mongo session?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have installed mongo on my server with `sudo yum install mongo`, i am using mongo to connect to my remote servers that actually have MongoDB installed on them (amazon servers).
At some point (during the backup restore) i need to issue a command like `mongod --dbpath /$dbPath --replSet $replicaSetName` on my MongoDb server, how can i do this from a mongo session? or if it is not possible, then how can i get the installation path to mongod?

Another thing is, i also have an mms account, is it possible to use their installed agent (on mongodb server) todo that?

thank you